# RMI call not adding callback listener

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I am having a problem understanding the inner workings of the program i am making.
The program is supposed to be an RMI client that contacts a server and registers itself. The server is then supposed to call a method on the client in a loop.
However, the listener is not being added.

Note the output. After adding the listener on the server, the method prints out the correct size, but the thread running the server does not, as the list remains empty. Why oh why is this happening?

Client

```
public class GameClient extends Thread implements Remote, Client, ModelChangeListener<Client>{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -394039736555035873L;
protected Queue<GameModelEvent> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<GameModelEvent>(); 


public GameClient(){

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    GameClient client = new GameClient();
    client.start();
}


protected void bind(){
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase","file:bin/");
    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        Client c = (Client)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 10999);
        Server stub = (Server) registry.lookup("Server");
        stub.registerClient(c);
    } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    bind();
    while(!Thread.interrupted()){
        System.out.print(".");
        GameModelEvent event = queue.poll();
        while(event != null){

            System.out.println(event);


            event = queue.poll();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }

}

   .....
}
```

Server

```
public class GameServer extends Thread implements ModelChangeListener<GameServer>, Server{
protected Queue<GameModelEvent> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<GameModelEvent>(); 
List<Client> clients = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Client>());

public static void main(String[] args){
    GameServer server = new GameServer();
    server.start();
}

protected void bind(){
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy","file:policy.policy");
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase","file:bin/");

    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
    try {
        String name = "Server";
        Server engine = new GameServer();
        Server stub =
            (Server) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registry.rebind(name, stub);
        System.out.println("ComputeEngine bound");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("GameServer exception:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void run() {
    super.run();
    bind();
    while(!Thread.interrupted()){
        System.out.print(clients.size()+ " ");

            try {
                for(Client c : clients)
                c.modifyConnection(null);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        GameModelEvent event = queue.poll();
        while(event != null){

            System.out.println(event);


            event = queue.poll();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }

}
@Override
public void registerClient(Client client) {
    System.out.println("\nAdded client "+client);
    clients.add(client);
    System.out.println("clients size "+clients.size());     
}
 ...
 }
```

Output

```
ComputeEngine bound
0 0 0 0 
Added client Proxy[Client,RemoteObjectInvocationHandler[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.117.2.88:10999](remote),objID:[5c30c56:13c5dfe5faf:-7fff, 1084850783049542281]]]]]
clients size 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance of `GameServer` you are binding is a different instance to the one you're creating in your main method.

It is the bound instance that will receive the RMI calls, while it is the main method instance that will be used by the thread - hence you have two different client lists.

In `GameServer` replace the line:

```
UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
```

With :

```
UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 0);
```

Comment: Oh for crying out loud! Of cause. Screw this i'm going to downvote myself for this one!:) thank you. Upvote and accept

Comment: Especially when working with something that you are not exactly sure how is supposed to work. You tend to shift focus from the obvious things "What if" problems